# Play framework - Starting & Stopping with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, playframework

I have an app I am deploying on the Play framework.
Following their guides (and because I don't want to rely on having play/sbt on the server) I am creating zip containing the relevant JAR's using "sbt dist". I then want to deploy/run the app.

I am doing the build and deploy via Jenkins. So I have a job that builds the zip. I then move the zip to the location and as per the docs I unzip the archive, go to the bin directory and run the app. Which raises 2 main questions.

1. What is the best way to start the app from Jenkins so that it doesn't block Jenkins and runs in the background. Currently I am doing the following...

   nohup ./my-play-app &

which works but doesn't feel right.

2. How do I stop the application?!!? My only solution at present is to run a "kill" command on the PID but that also doesn't feel right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case i have written start.sh and stop.sh files with the above mentioned commands, from Jenkins before doing the new deployment i am calling stop.sh file, it will stop the running application, then i am coping the new source code in to the same location after that i am calling start.sh file so it will run the application.

Check my start.sh file                                                                                      #!/bin/bash
    nohup /home/PlayApplications/AppName/bin/app -Dhttp.port=5252
 &                                                                                                                               Stop.sh file-                                                                                                        #!/bin/bash
    pid=`cat /home/PlayApplications/AppName/RUNNING_PID 2> /dev/null`
    if [ "$pid" == "" ]; then echo "play app is not running"; exit 0; fi
    echo "Stopping play app..."
    kill -SIGTERM $pid                                                                                      Before killing the pid i am checking whether my application is running or not, if is running i am stoping by using kill comand

Comment: so you are also using nohup and kill?

Comment: Yes i am alos using nohup and kill